# How to set date range selection in react JS DateRangePicker?

Tags: reactjs, daterangepicker

I am using 'DateRangePicker' component in my react JS application.
I am trying to restrict start date to last 6 month only and difference between 
start and end date should not be more than 1 month.
I wrote following code

```
isOutsideRange = (day) => {
  if (day > moment()) return true;
  else if (this.state.startDate) {
    if (day > moment(this.state.endDate)) return true;
    if (day < moment().subtract(6, 'months')) return true;
    else return false;
  } else if (this.state.endDate) {
    if (day > moment(this.state.endDate)) return true;
    if ((moment(this.state.endDate) > (moment(this.state.startDate).subtract(1, 'month')))) return true;
    else return false;
  }
}
```

and here is the UI code

```
<DateRangePicker
  startDate={this.state.startDate}
  startDateId="validFromDate"
  endDate={this.state.endDate}
  endDateId="validToDate"
  onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) =>
    this.handleValidDatesChange(startDate, endDate)
  }
  focusedInput={this.state.ofrFocusedInput}
  onFocusChange={(ofrFocusedInput) => this.setState({ ofrFocusedInput })}
  isOutsideRange={(e) => this.isOutsideRange(e)}
  showDefaultInputIcon={true}
  small={true}
  minimumNights={0}
  hideKeyboardShortcutsPanel={true}
  showClearDates={true}
  min={this.maxDate}
  shouldDisableDate={({ startDate }) => this.disablePrevDates(startDate)}
  // minDate={subDays(new Date(), 10)}
  displayFormat={() => "DD/MM/YYYY"}
/>;
```

I tried to debug but it is not working.
Can someone suggest the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a moment is between two other moments, optionally looking at unit scale (minutes, hours, days, etc), you should use:

```
moment().isBetween(moment-like, moment-like, String, String);
// where moment-like is Moment|String|Number|Date|Array
```

For instance, if you need to check `today - 6months <= someDate <= today`, you would use something like:

```
// returns TRUE if date is outside the range
const isOutsideRange = date => {
    const now = moment();
    return !moment(date)
             .isBetween(now.subtract(6, 'months'), now, undefined, '[]');
    // [] - match is inclusive
}
```

For more details, please check [Is Between docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/). This method is very flexible, for instance, you can have exclusive or inclusive match.

Now, the second condition. If you would like to check if `endDate - startDate <= 1 month`, you can play with moments as well to achieve this.

```
// so if you add 1 month to your startDate and then your end date
// is still before the result or the same - you can say the duration
// between them is 1 month
const lessThanMonth = (startDate, endDate) => {
    return endDate.isSameOrBefore(moment(startDate).add(1, 'months'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (day.isAfter(moment()) || 
   !day.isAfter(moment().subtract(6,'months'))) return true;
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.